# Animations in UITableView effects last row in previous section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

We have a UITableView where we have heavily customized the backgrounds and colors.  We are changing the code for the section headers to expand and collapse.  The code is similar to this example:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html

When it collapses, we see the last item in the previous section change, but then revert back to the right cell.  It looks like it animates up into that cell, but then draws itself correctly.

Is this an iOS 7 issue, an issue with some of our customizations, or any other ideas?

Edit: I think I solved the issue.  Here was the code where we change what is shown when the section header is tapped.  I think its doing the animation twice?

```
- (void)sectionHeaderView:(MenuTableViewHeaderFooterView *)sectionHeaderView sectionOpened:(NSInteger)sectionOpened {

    MenuSectionInfo *sectionInfo = [self.sectionInfoArray objectAtIndex:sectionOpened];
    sectionInfo.collapsed = NO;

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSArray *collapsedHeaders = [defaults stringArrayForKey:@"menu-collapsed"];
    NSMutableSet *collapsedHeadersSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithArray:collapsedHeaders];
    [collapsedHeadersSet removeObject:sectionInfo.headerTitle];
    collapsedHeaders = [collapsedHeadersSet allObjects];
    [defaults setObject:collapsedHeaders forKey:@"menu-collapsed"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    NSArray *modules = sectionInfo.modules;

    NSInteger countOfRowsToInsert = [modules count];
    NSMutableArray *indexPathsToInsert = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < countOfRowsToInsert; i++) {
        [indexPathsToInsert addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:sectionOpened]];
    }

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToInsert withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

- (void)sectionHeaderView:(MenuTableViewHeaderFooterView *)sectionHeaderView sectionClosed:(NSInteger)sectionClosed {

    MenuSectionInfo *sectionInfo = (self.sectionInfoArray)[sectionClosed];

    sectionInfo.collapsed = YES;

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSArray *collapsedHeaders = [defaults stringArrayForKey:@"menu-collapsed"];
    NSMutableSet *collapsedHeadersSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithArray:collapsedHeaders];
    [collapsedHeadersSet addObject:sectionInfo.headerTitle];
    collapsedHeaders = [collapsedHeadersSet allObjects];
    [defaults setObject:collapsedHeaders forKey:@"menu-collapsed"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    NSInteger countOfRowsToDelete = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:sectionClosed];

    if (countOfRowsToDelete > 0) {
        NSMutableArray *indexPathsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < countOfRowsToDelete; i++) {
            [indexPathsToDelete addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:sectionClosed]];
        }
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }
}
```

If I change (insert/delete)RowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: to use animation UITableViewRowAnimationNone, it looks animated without this issue.

Comment: We cant possibly come up with a conclusive answer to explain whats  going on without seeing how you've coded it all. Chances are there are some issues with your coding in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, especially when theres animation involved. You might also be missing methods that are required to be invoked before anything is drawn. such as the `willDisplayCell` method. Thats all I can say from what you've told us so far.

Comment: I wish I could add more, but this table is in a very complicated part of our app, that I should try to create another app with the problem than try to paste the code here.

I should add, that this weird behavior only happens the first time.  If we collapse/expand/collapse a section, the odd animation only happens the first time.

Comment: Why did you mention willDisplayCell?  We are not adding that method in our delegate.  What did you think we should put there?

Comment: allow me to rephrase: "..that MAY need to be added in to fix any weird issues". I really cannot say exactly what you can put in there, it all depends on how you guys are handling it all.
`I should try to create another app with the problem`, Yes I believe thats a good idea; You can simplify the project/scale it down to the problem alone and then paste a link to that project over here, and I'll take a look at it :)

Comment: Also, can I suggest you do a screen recording so that you can present the problem on the simulator. It might give a better idea of whats going on while youre trying to scale down the code into a new project.

Comment: A test project that isolates/demonstrates the issue will do two things: 1. make it easier for anyone here to help you because they don't have to look through tons of code. 2. It will help you debug your own issues. As you start removing parts of the code that don't pertain to the issue may find the offending/buggy code that's causing the issue.